# Is impersonation in Win32 per thread?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, impersonation, sspi

Is calling [`ImpersonateSecurityContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375497.aspx) on the server impersonating the client on the calling thread or for the entire process. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375497.aspx) is a bit vague on the matter as it states that *"The function creates an impersonation token and allows the thread or process to run with the impersonation context"*.

I assume that impersonation is only for the calling thread, anything else would be strange, but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per MSDN:

[Client Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376391.aspx)

> Impersonation is the ability of **a thread** to execute using different security information than the process that owns the thread. Typically, **a thread** in a server application impersonates a client. This allows the server **thread** to act on behalf of that client to access objects on the server or validate access to the client's own objects.
>
> The Microsoft Windows API provides the following functions to begin an impersonation:
>   ...
>   - A security package or application server can call the `ImpersonateSecurityContext` function to impersonate a client.

So Impersonation is done on a per-thread basis.

Impersonation can be used to spawn a new process as the impersonated user (by using [`DuplicateTokenEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446617.aspx) and [`CreateProcessAsUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429.aspx)) but impersonation never makes the calling *process* run as the impersonated user, only the calling *thread*.

In a server context, where multiple clients can be connected at the same time, it would be very dangerous if client impersonation was applied on a process-wide basic.

Comment: I understand that it would be strange, dangerous and outright stupid if impersonation was process-wide, but I have not found any documentation that states it is per-thread. Do you have some official documentation to support this?